# UnionSet by rank with a strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I was trying to make a union by rank program of cities that can be connected 
 And
I just realized, that if I want to union parents, I need to put both cities into one parent, so if i have

```
parent[0][20] = "City"
parent[1][20] = "Cities"
```

I need to make it

```
parent[1] = "City", "Cities";
```

And when checking `isSameSet` I also have to look at `parent[i]` is containing both

```
parent[i] = "City", "Cities";
```

Is this possible with 2d array? Or could I use 3d array to make the strings goes:

```
parent[i][j][k]
parent[0][0][20] = "City"
parent[0][1][20] = "Cities"
```

Can I even do that? I have no idea, or should I just use `struct/linked list` instead? Can anyone give me some clue or advice, about how to do union sets with strings?? 
*Edit: I also don't think my findSet(); function would work, if I use 2d arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>


void initialize(char parent[][20], int *ranks, char x[], int i){

    strcpy(parent[i], x);
    ranks[i] = 0;

}

int findSet(char parent[][20], char x[], int n){

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(strcmp(parent[i], x) == 0){
            return i;
        } else{
            printf("City not found!\n");
        }
    }
}

int isSameSet(char parent[][20], char x[], char y[], int n){

    if(strcmp(parent[findSet(parent, x, n)], parent[findSet(parent, y, n)]) == 0) return 1;
        else return 0;

}

void unionSet(char parent[][20], int *ranks, char x[], char y[], int n){

    int i = findSet(parent, x, n);
    int j = findSet(parent, y, n);

    if(i != j){
        if(ranks[i] > ranks[j]){
            parent[j] = 1;
        } else {
            if(ranks[i] == ranks[j]){
                ranks[j]++;
            }
            parent[i] = j;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int n, i = 0, choice;
    char x[20], y[20];

    printf("Enter the number of cities : "); scanf("%d", &n);

    char parent[n][20];
    int ranks[n];

    while(1){
        system("cls");
        printf("================================================\n");
        printf("            City Connection Program\n");
        printf("================================================\n");
        printf("1. Enter City\n");
        printf("2. Connect city\n");
        printf("3. Check cities connected\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Pilihan: ");scanf("%d", &choice); fflush(stdin);

        if(choice == 1){
            if(i < n){
                printf("Enter city name: "); scanf("%[^\n]", x);fflush(stdin);
                initialize(parent, ranks, x, i);
                i++;
                printf("City %s is entered\n", parent[i]);
            } else{
                printf("The city is at maximum!\n");
            }
        } else if( choice == 2){
            printf("Enter city 1: ");scanf("%[^\n]", x);
            printf("Enter city 2: ");scanf("%[^\n]", y);
            if(isSameSet(parent, x, y, n)){
                printf("Both cities are already Connected\n");
            } else{
                unionSet(parent, ranks, x, y, n);
                printf("Both cities are connected!\n");
            }

        }
        /*else if(choice == 3){
            printf("Enter city 1: ");scanf("%[^\n]", x);
            printf("Enter city 2: ");scanf("%[^\n]", y);
            if(isSameSet(parent, x, y)) printf("City %s and city %s connected\n", x, y);
                else printf("City %s and city %s is not connected\n", x, y");
        } else if(choice == 4){
            return 1;
        }

        getch();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: make your code compile first. Your code have the errors at `parent[j] = 1` and `parent[i] = j`, for example

Comment: Nesting arrays of chars is not a good solution here. Make an array of names for citys (a 2d array of chars), then make the parent reference an integer that is an index to the first index to that array or −1 to mean "no parent". You don't need the `strcmp` comparisons then, only plain integer comparisons with `==`. Use the string only for input and output, not for the set logic.

Comment: (And if you already learned about structs, make each city a struct, which avoids spreading the data across disjoint arrays.)

Comment: Do not do `fflush(stdin);`,it's undefiend behavior. `scanf("%[^\n]"` Leaves a newline in the buffer. The second `scanf("%[^\n]", y);` will read nothing. Do `scanf("\n%19[^\n]"` Or read the newline explicitly with `getchar`

Comment: @Hitokiri yeah, that's what I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @MOehm can you explain ```"make the parent reference an integer that is an index to the first index to that array or -1 to mean "no parent"```
So the array of names is the parent ? or are there separate parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a list of `n` cities, identified by their names:

```
char city[n][20] = {"Amsterdam", "Beijing", "Cairo", ..., "Zurich"};
```

Note that each city is also identified by the position in the array: Amsterdam is 0, Brussels is 1, and so on.

These cities are to be grouped into disjoint sets. The sets are describes as trees. Each city has a parent. A city that has itself as parent is the root city for that set. It identifies the set.

So you must store the parent somehow. Your idea is to store the name of the parent and then to compare the names as you find the root node:

```
char parent[n][20];        // initialize to same strings as city
```

You can do that, but it would be easier if you just stored the parant index:

```
int parent[n];
```

When you connect two cities, you must first determine which cities they are. You must determine the `n` that you pass to your functions. (You pass `n` , which in `main` is the number of cities and therefore the dimeison of the array. In C, `n` is one beyond the valid range of array indices.)

Finally, you get your ranks:

```
int rank[n];
```

Now you need the following functions:

A function to relate a string to an index. This function can fail when the city isn't found, so it can return a wrong index, `-1` to indicate a look-up error. It needs to know the number of cities and the cty names. It doesn't need to know about the sets.

```
int findCity(char city[][20], int n, const char *name)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strcmp(city[i], name) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

A function to find the set of a city, that is the "root city" for a set. This function only nees to know about the parent of each city. If the array is set up properly, i.e. if `k` and all possible `parent[k]` are valid indices, and if the parent of thr root is the root itself, this function cannot fail. Then this function does not need to know about the number of cities:

```
int findSet(int parent[], int k)
{
    while (parent[k] != k) {
        k = parent[k];
    }

    return k;
}
```

A function to determine whether two cities are the same. This really is just a "convenience function" to `findSet`:

```
int isSameSet(int parent[], int a, int b)
{
    return (findSet(parent, a) == findSet(parent, b));
}
```

Finally, the function to join two sets: It needs to know about the ranks in addition to the parents, but again, if all arrays are set up correctly, there's no need to pass the number of cities. This is exactly the function as you wrote it:

```
void unionSet(int parent[], int rank[], int a, int b)
{
    int s = findSet(parent, a);
    int t = findSet(parent, b);

    if (s != t) {
        if (rank[s] > rank[t]) {
            parent[t] = s;
        } else {
            if (rank[s] == rank[t]) rank[t]++;            
            parent[s] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

See an example [in action here](https://ideone.com/lSQFU0).

To recap: Use the cities' names only for the user interface, when you take input and when you print output. Do the logic of the sets on integer indices.

Additional notes:

- A better representation might be to create a city struct that contains the data for each city including the parent and rank. Instead of integer indices, you can then use pointers to these structs.
- At the moment, most of the time is wasted by looking up cities in the array. That's okay for a small example, but in a real program, you would have to use at least binary search to look up the names.

Comment: @M Oehm sorry for the late reply, Thank you for the answer! I am using struct to store the cities name, and then simply compare the index of struct with the parents, it is the same idea as using char[n][20] too,  Thanks once again!